# Including Double Quotes in Batch Search and Replace script

Tags: batch-file

I have a config file on many remote machines that I need to modify through the use of a batch script. The config file has two lines like this:

```
1_IP = "10.101.34.216"
2_IP = "10.101.34.214"
```

I simply need to swap the two IP's, but I'm having a hard time.

Ideally, I would write a simple script to search for `10.101.34.216` and replace it with `10.101.34.214` and vice versa - however, if I accidentally run the script on the remote machines in the future it would just revert to the original.

Therefore, I need to set the search parameter to look for exactly `1_IP = "10.101.34.216"` and replace it with exactly `1_IP = "10.101.34.214"` and then subsequently an exact search for `2_IP = "10.101.34.214"` to be replaced with exactly `2_IP = "10.101.34.216"`

I'm currently using the following script, which I found on a separate stackoverflow post.

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=%1"
set "replace=%2"

set "textFile=system.cfg"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
```

However, if I set search parameter to

```
set search= "1_IP = "10.101.34.216" "
```

It does not work because of the double quotes. I've tried several approaches to escape the double quotes, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance for your time, patience, and expertise.

Comment: I would take a different approach.  Two options.  1) Uses the tokens option of the FOR /F command and check if the first token equals 1_IP. 2)Do a findstr on the line variable.  If you find IP_1 echo the appropriate output to the config file instead of the line variable. Do a second findstr for the other ip.

Comment: Does it have to be batch?  PowerShell, or even VBScript, will eat this up.

Comment: What wrong with just overwriting the content of the file? You already know the two exact lines you're dealing with, the name of the file and the location. `@(Echo/1_IP = "10.101.34.216"&Echo/2_IP = "10.101.34.214")>"X:\Path\system.cfg"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the current strings behind `1_IP =` and `2_IP =` do not seem to matter, I would not try to replace them, but I would simply write the desired strings, like this (see all the explanatory `rem` comments):

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~dp0system.cfg" & rem // (path/name of file to process)
set "_KEY[1]=1_IP"          & rem // (1st key to search for)
set "_KEY[2]=2_IP"          & rem // (2nd key to search for)
set "_VAL[1]=10.101.34.214" & rem // (1st value to assign to 1st key)
set "_VAL[2]=10.101.34.216" & rem // (2nd value to assign to 2nd key)

rem // Read specified file and iterate through all (non-empty) lines:
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('type "%_FILE%" ^& ^> "%_FILE%" rem/') do (
    rem // Write (append) to the specified file:
    >> "%_FILE%" (
        rem // Split key from value (key must not contain spaces):
        for /F "eol== delims== " %%K in ("%%L") do (
            rem /* If key is a predefined one return respective value;
            rem    otherwise return the current line unedited: */
            if /I "%%K"=="%_KEY[1]%" (
                echo(%%K = "%_VAL[1]%"
            ) else if /I "%%K"=="%_KEY[2]%" (
                echo(%%K = "%_VAL[2]%"
            ) else (
                echo(%%L
            )
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

If you want to be able to predefine an arbitrary number of keys and values, and to retain empty lines, you may want to use this script:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~dp0system.cfg" & rem // (path/name of file to process)
set "_KEY[1]=1_IP"          & rem // (1st key to search for)
set "_KEY[2]=2_IP"          & rem // (2nd key to search for)
set "_VAL[1]=10.101.34.214" & rem // (1st value to assign to 1st key)
set "_VAL[2]=10.101.34.216" & rem // (2nd value to assign to 2nd key)

rem // Read specified file and iterate through all lines, preceded by line number:
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_FILE%" ^& ^> "%_FILE%" rem/') do (
    rem // Write (append) to the specified file:
    >> "%_FILE%" (
        rem // Split line number plus key from value (key must not contain spaces):
        for /F "delims== " %%K in ("%%L") do (
            rem // Store extracted key and full line, both including line numbers:
            set "KEY=%%K" & set "LINE=%%L"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Clear flag, remove line number from key:
            set "FLAG=" & set "KEY=!KEY:*:=!"
            rem // Loop through all available keys:
            for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]=" %%M in ('2^> nul set _KEY[') do (
                rem /* If key is a predefined one return respective value;
                rem    otherwise set flag to indicate key has been found: */
                if /I "!KEY!"=="!_KEY[%%M]!%" (
                    echo(!KEY! = "!_VAL[%%M]!"
                    set "FLAG=#"
                )
            )
            rem // Return current line unedited in case flag is not set:
            if not defined FLAG echo(!LINE:*:=!
            endlocal
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q41578841.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "search1=1_IP = \"10.101.34.216\""
SET "search2=2_IP = \"10.101.34.214\""
SET "replace1=1_IP = "10.101.34.214""
SET "replace2=2_IP = "10.101.34.216""

SET "replaced=N"
(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 ECHO(%%a|FINDSTR /x /L /C:"%search1%" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  ECHO(%%a|FINDSTR /x /L /C:"%search2%" >NUL
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO(%%a
  ) ELSE (SET "replaced=Y"&ECHO(%replace2%
  )
 ) ELSE (SET "replaced=Y"&ECHO(%replace1%
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

IF %replaced%==Y (MOVE "%outfile%" "%filename1%">nul&ECHO made changes
) ELSE (DEL "%outfile%"&echo no changes made
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q41578841.txt` containing your data plus some dummy data for my testing.

%outfile% may be used as a temporary file. its name is not relevant, it just needs to not-exist when the job is run.

read each file line. if the line exactly matches (`/x`) the search-string (`/c:` since it may contain spaces, `/L` literally - `/i` for case-insensitive omitted) then set `errorlevel` 0. if neither matches, regurgitate the line, else output the replacement line and flag that the replacement took place.

Finally, either replace the file or delete the dummy output file and report.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but when is Windows Shell script?...:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set TEXT_FILE=.\system.cfg
set IP_1=
set IP_2=
for /f "tokens=*" %%L in (%TEXT_FILE%) do call :PROCESS_LINE %%L

echo 1_IP = "%IP_2%"
echo 2_IP = "%IP_1%"

endlocal
goto END

:PROCESS_LINE
set PL_LINE=%*
set PL_LINE=%PL_LINE:"=%
if "%PL_LINE:~0,4%" == "1_IP" set IP_1=%PL_LINE:~7%
if "%PL_LINE:~0,4%" == "2_IP" set IP_2=%PL_LINE:~7%
goto END

:END
```